# Dimension of $V\cap V^{\perp}$ over field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory

I'm wondering if this is true:

> Let $F \subset K$ be fields $V$ an $K$-vector space.  If $U\subset V$  then
>   $$\dim_{F}(U\cap U^{\perp}) \leq \dim_{K}(U\cap U^{\perp})$$
>   where the $U^{\perp}$ is with respect to a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form.

Any hints, proofs, counter examples or references are welcome!

As for what I've tried:  I tried finding a counter example of the form $V = \mathbb{Q}\cdot \{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}\}$ ect and finding a bilinear form and a subspace such that $\dim(U\cap U^{\perp}) > 1.$ This would obviously suffice because then when we extend to $\mathbb{R}$, $\dim V = 1$ so $\dim(U\cap U^{\perp}) \leq 1.$  No luck with such a counter example so far, everything I've come up with give $\dim(U\cap U^{\perp}) = 1.$

I also tried giving a proof but I haven't gotten very far.  Once we extend the field its not clear at all what happens to the basis of $(U\cap U^{\perp}).$

**UPDATE**
I think maybe I'm thinking about this backwards.  I was assuming $\langle ,\rangle$ was defined over $F$ and that it could be extending to being defined over $K.$  But I'm not sure that is always possible.  So maybe what I am really wonder is if we have $\langle , \rangle$ defined over $K$ and we restrict to $F$ what happens?

As for motivation, I'm reading a proof which claims that "$\dim(U\cap U^{\perp})$ does not increase over a field extension thus..." It seems to me that to logically complete the proof it must be that it only possibly increases.

Comment: You have to assume that $V$ is a $K$-vector space... For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, but not a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Comment: You are claiming that the dimension over the smaller field is no greater than the dimension over the bigger field?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Ok, maybe I'm miss understanding my own question then.  I will edit to add that assumption and update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, $\langle,\rangle$ has to be a $K$-bilinear form, and $U$ also has to be a subspace with respect to $K$. That way $U\cap U^\perp$ will be a vetor space over both $K$ and $F$, so you can talk about dimension.

That said, the result you wat is actually backwards, and you should easily prove the following:

> Let $W$ be a vector space over $K$, and let $F$ be a subfield of $K$. Then
>   $$\dim_K(W)\leq\dim_F(W).$$

Hint: If $B\subseteq W$ is $K$-linearly independent, then it also is $F$-linearly independent. In your problem, use $W=U\cap U^\perp$.

Comment: Yes, this is the more natural thing to expect.  I suppose I really don't understand the proof I am reading then.  It must depend on something more specific to the situation at hand.  The theorem is about an absolutely reducible group representation and it is proven that $\dim U/U\cap U^{\perp}$ stays the same over the field extension and so it is claimed that this proves $\dim U\cap U^{\perp}$ does not increase, but I don't see why the second statement is relevant or even true (both the $U$ and $U\cap U^{\perp}$ could decrease proportionally).